# Is there any command to launch directory in file manager of android using adb?

Tags: command, adb, android-debugging, android-shell

I want to open Download folder in my android phone using adb. I have example: 
`start . /path/to/that/folder` command for command-prompt and `nautilus /path/to/that/folder` for ubuntu terminal.